How to prove that $M_2\left(K\right)$ is isomorphic to $K$, where $K$ is the $C^*$-algebra of all compact operators in the separable $H$ilbert space?
Suppose $K$ is the $C^*$-algebra of all compact operators in the separable Hilbert space. Let $M_{2}\left(K\right)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix} \mid a,b,c,d\in K\right\}$. How to prove that $M_{2}\left(K\right)$ is isomorphic to $K$?

What have you tried? Hint: all infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to $\ell^2$ (and thus to each other).

Additional hint: elements of $M_2(K)$ act naturally as compact operators on $\ell^2 \oplus \ell^2$, and in fact all compact operators on $\ell^2 \oplus \ell^2$ arise this way.

Thank you for your hints.

More generally if $H$ is any infinite-dimensional Hilbert space then (for any $n\in\Bbb N$) $H\cong H^n$ hence $K(H)\cong K(H^n)=M_n(K(H))$.

@AnneBauval Thank you for your hint. What will happen if we replace $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with $\infty$? Does the following equation $K\left(\oplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}} H\right)=M_{\infty}\left(K\left(H\right)\right)$? Maybe, according to the remark in the answer, I think that the equation $K\left(\oplus_{i\in \mathbb{N}} H\right)=K\otimes K$ is better. Above all, Thank you very much for your hint again.

@BrunoB Thank you very much for your hint.

@HaoWang I agree, provided $\oplus_{i\in \Bbb N}$ and $\otimes$ mean the (natural) completions of the algebraic direct sum and tensor product.

@AnneBauval I suppose I shouldn't have been so hasty to see "isomorphic" as "isomorphic as Banach/Hilbert spaces" in my now deleted answer... Thanks for noticing the issue!

As we all know, any separable Hilbert space is isomorphic to $l^2$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $K=K\left(lˆ2\right)$. Define the isomorphism $u$ from $l^{2}\oplus l^{2}$ to $l^{2}$ as follow,
\begin{align*}
\left(\xi_i\right)\oplus\left(\eta_i\right)\mapsto \left(\xi_1,\eta_1,\xi_2,\eta_2,\cdots\right).
\end{align*}
A routine computing show that $Adu: K\left(l^{2}\oplus l^{2}\right)\to K\left(l^2\right)$ is an isomorphism between $C^*$-algebras. To show $M_2\left(K\right)$ is isomorphic to $K$, we need only to show that $M_2\left(K\right)$ is isomorphic to $K\left(l^{2}\oplus l^{2}\right)$. Define a map from $M_2\left(K\right)$ to $K\left(l^{2}\oplus l^{2}\right)$ as follow,
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
ax+by\\
cx+dy
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $x,y\in l^2$, and $a,b,c,d\in K$. Applying the definition that compact operators transform bounded set to the relative sequence compact set, we conclude that the previous map is well defined. Let $P_i$ be the $i$-th projection from $l^{2}\oplus l^{2}$ to $l^{2}$, $i=1,2$. For any element $A\in K\left(l^{2}\oplus l^{2}\right)$, Define the following maps,
\begin{align*}
ax=P_1A\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
0
\end{pmatrix},
by=P_1A
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
y
\end{pmatrix},
cx=P_2A\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
0
\end{pmatrix},
dy=P_2A\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
y
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Clearly, $a,b,c,d\in K$ and
\begin{equation*}
A\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
In fact, the pre-image of $A$ is
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{pmatrix}
P_1Ai_1&P_1Ai_2\\
P_2Ai_1&P_2Ai_2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
where $i_k$ is the $k$-th inclusion from $l^2$ to $l^2\oplus l^2$. It is easy to check that the map is an isomorphism.
Remark : Applying the same method, we may show that $M_n\left(K\right)$ is isomorphic to $K$ for every positive integer. Due to technique of inductive limit, we reach that $K\otimes K$ is isomorphic to  $K$.

Remark: $M_n\left(B\left(H\right)\right)$ is isomorphic to $B\left(H\oplus\cdots\oplus H\right)$. In particularly, $M_n\left(B\left(l^2\right)\right)$ is isomorphic to $B\left(l^2\oplus\cdots\oplus l^2\right)$, and hence $M_n\left(B\left(l^2\right)\right)$ is isomorphic to $B\left(l^2\right)$, where $l^2$ is a separable Hilbert space.
